# How to handle up button inside fragment using Navigation Components

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, android-architecture-components, android-jetpack

I am making a simple note taking app, I have 2 fragments with navigation component, one fragment has a list of notes and the other is for editing or creating a new note.

In `MainActivity` I added

```
val navController = this.findNavController(R.id.host_fragment)
NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController)
```

and then override `onSupportNavigateUp()`

```
override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        val navController = this.findNavController(R.id.host_fragment)
        return navController.navigateUp()
    }
```

In `NoteEditFragment`

```
requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(this) {
        saveOrUpdateNote(noteId, note)
    }
```

now it all works well when pressing the "back button" in the device, However `onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback()` is note triggered when I press the "up button" the one on the top left of the screen.

My question is : How do I handle this up button from my `NoteEditFragment`?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution.

First In the `activity` `onCreate` method I had to connect the navigation like I did:

```
val navController = this.findNavController(R.id.host_fragment)
NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController)
```

Then still in `MainActivity` override `onSupportNavigateUp()` :

```
override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean
{
    val navController = this.findNavController(R.id.host_fragment)
    return navController.navigateUp()
}
```

Then In the `Fragment` `onCreateView` I had to enable option menu:

```
setHasOptionsMenu(true)
```

then in the `fragment` I overridden `onOptionsItemSelected` :

```
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean
{
    // handle the up button here
    return NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected(item!!,
        view!!.findNavController())
            || super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
}
```

Note: I think if you have more than one option menu, then I think you have to do a `when (item)` statement to check what option has been chosen.

Also if you want to handle the device back button then you can do like this in your `fragment` `onCreateViewMethod` :

```
requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(this)
    {
        // handle back button

// change this line to whatever way you chose to navigate back          
findNavController().navigate(NoteEditFragmentDirections.actionNoteEditFragmentToNoteListFragment())
        }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'd forgotten how to handle the up Button !!

Comment: super clean and smooth

Comment: for those who are looking for the item.itemid of the back button on the action bar it is: android.R.id.home. see: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.id#home

Answer (score 2):

I think the accepted answer is a bit messy. So, i found a clean code. It is perfect for my use case as i don't need to do anything special when the device back button is pressed. Therefore, anyone here with the same requirements can follow my code.

In onCreate of MainActivity:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
    appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(navController.graph)
    // Check if androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController is imported
    // By default title in actionbar is used from the fragment label in navigation graph
    // To use the app name, remove label else if you want to add customized label specify it there
    setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration)

    ...

  }
```

Again, in the MainActivity itself:

```
override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
    val navController = findNavController(R.id.fragment)
    // Check if androidx.Navigation.ui navigateUp is imported and used
    return navController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration) || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
}
```

I have added comments for better understanding. If you think the answer is helpful then please upvote. Thank You. Happy Development :)

**EDIT 1:**
No need to use `supportActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)` in the fragments. AppBarConfiguration will take care of it.

Answer (score 0):

if you use noActionBar themes and you want to use your own toolbar as an actionBar for the fragment, you can use this method

in the host activity

```
override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
    return findNavController(R.id.navHostFragment).navigateUp()
}
```

in the onCreateView of the fragment

```
(activity as AppCompatActivity).setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbar)
(activity as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
```

Answer (score 0):

in very simple way you just need to set the supportNavigateUp on the Activity.

in **MainActivity**:

```
private lateinit var navController: NavController

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment
    navController = navHostFragment.navController

    setupActionBarWithNavController(navController)
}

override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
    return navController.navigateUp() || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
}
```

in my case its worked