# Navigating back to previous fragment - NavGraph

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation

I am navigating from one fragment to another using NavGraph - Navigation UI component.

The physical button the device works for navigation, but how do i activate the back arrow on the top of app to go back to previous fragment

[image]

NavGraph

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/charactersFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/charactersFragment"
        android:name="com.example.breakingbad.CharactersFragment"
        android:label="fragment_characters"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_characters" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_charactersFragment_to_characterDetailFragment"
            app:destination="@id/characterDetailFragment" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/characterDetailFragment"
        android:name="com.example.breakingbad.CharacterDetailFragment"
        android:label="fragment_character_detail"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_character_detail" />
</navigation>
```

CharacterDetailFragment - this does not do much at the moment

```
class CharacterDetailFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        arguments?.let {
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_character_detail, container, false)
    }
}
```

Activity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.fragment)
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController)
    }
}
```

EDIT

Updated the activity code to this and it worked

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var navController: NavController

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.fragment)
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController)
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        return navController.navigateUp() || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
    }
}
```

Thanks
R

Comment: Can you show the code in the activity?

Comment: updated the question with activity

Comment: Are you implement this with the Navigation drawer Layout??

Answer (score 4):

We call that the "Up" navigation button. See here for discussion about this issue:

[How to handle up button inside fragment using Navigation Components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57635268/how-to-handle-up-button-inside-fragment-using-navigation-components)

The solution will, at the very least, require using the `setupActionBarWithNavController()` method.

Comment: Thank you @Gavin

updated the activity with the following code and it worked fine thank you

Comment: class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var navController: NavController

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.fragment)
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController)
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        return navController.navigateUp() || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
    }
}

Answer (score 2):

Simply Add `onSupportNavigateUp()` to your main activity

```
override fun onSupportNavigateUp() = navController.navigateUp()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you implement this with the navigation drawer layout then use this line for back to the previous fragment But if you want to implement the navigation component with Bottom navigation and navigation drawer layout [click here](https://github.com/anwarzahid8284/Navigation-Component-With-drawer-layout-and-Bottom-Navigation). Just it explains for future help.

```
appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(navController.graph, drawerLayoutID)
NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController,
     drawerLayoutID)
```